# How can I create a view in a SQL Server database with C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, view

How do I create a view dynamically in SQL Server using C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this, obviously your connection code will be different (better):

```
SqlConnection conn = null;
conn = new SqlConnection("yourConnectionString");
conn.Open();
string strSQLCommand = "CREATE VIEW vw_YourView AS SELECT YOurColumn FROM YourTable";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strSQLCommand, conn); 
string returnvalue = (string)command.ExecuteScalar(); 
conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code to write the query for a view:

```
query = " Create View [Viewname] Select ....";
```

Execute the query.