# Create a View in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010

I'm converting a program I prototyped in Visual Basic into C# in Visual Studio 2010, and I'm having trouble with the Database. Specifically, I can't create a View. There's no folder for Views in the Server Explorer, and I can't save a Query. Is there a way to save a View that I'm not seeing? Or is there a different thing to do the stuff a View does?

Comment: Similar topic to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336731/how-can-i-create-a-view-in-a-sql-server-database-with-c

Comment: Hmm. My search didn't turn up that result. Thank you!